# CSS hyperlink styling

Tags: css

I am successfully styling links leading to document downloads using such styling as below:

```
a[href $='.pdf']{
  background-image: url('http://myserver/pdficon_sm.gif');
}
```

There many links to apply specific document icons to but there also are other links which connect to html pages and of course have no document extension.

**I am trying to find a way to target all hyperlinks which have a *.ext*, with ext being anything like .doc, .pdf etc.** Unfortunately, the markup does not have descriptive class data nor do I have access to add classes.

This is so I can avoid repeating code like padding etc for all the target document extensions AND also to exclude non-document extension hyperlinks

**ps:**

apologies if my first draft was unclear about the problem

Comment: The problem here is what, exactly?

Comment: Do you want a general rule for all extensions like `a[href $='.<ext>']{
  background-image: url('http://myserver/<ext>icon_sm.gif');
}`? That's not possible with pure CSS, only with JS.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Well, you will probably have to use Javascript on document ready to identify those links and assign a class to them. In CSS, there is probably no solution possible for your specific requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I can see no single CSS selector that you can use to target all and only all links of these types and apply generic styles to them *unless you provide a little more information when your server generates those links*.

I'd recommend using a data-attribute for this and put it on the generated link's html:

```
<a data-linktype="non-web-document" href="files/myPdf.pdf">myPdf</a>
```

and then use the attribute selector for creating a generic ruleset for this linktype:

```
a[data-linktype="non-web-document"] {
    /* you css that applies to all those links */
}
```

Or, even easier and more straight-forward, use a css class for it:

```
<a class="file-link" href="files/myPdf.pdf">myPdf</a>

a.file-link {
    /* you css that applies to all those links */
}
```

Provided your file extension icon names follow a strict naimng convention, you can save yourself quite some typing/c&p effort by using [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-directive) to generate the document-type-specific rules for you.

```
@each $fileExtension in pdf, docx, xls, doc {
  a[href$=".#{$fileExtension}"] {
    background-image: url('/images/#{$fileExtension}icon_sm.png');
  }
}
```

would generate to

```
a[href$=".pdf"] {
  background-image: url("/images/pdficon_sm.png");
}

a[href$=".docx"] {
  background-image: url("/images/docxicon_sm.png");
}

a[href$=".xls"] {
  background-image: url("/images/xlsicon_sm.png");
}

a[href$=".doc"] {
  background-image: url("/images/docicon_sm.png");
}
```

> #### @each
>
> The `@each` directive usually has the form `@each $var in <list or map>`. `$var` can be any variable name, like `$length` or `$name`, and `<list or map>` is a SassScript expression that returns a list or a map. The `@each` rule sets `$var` to each item in the list or map, then outputs the styles it contains using that value of `$var`.
>
> http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-directive

If you want to experiment with this first, you may want to use [SassMeister.com](http://sassmeister.com/) for quick tests.